# Predicting the next few numbers

Tags: forecasting

I have data that looks like this

[image]

I just want to predict the rest of 2013. What is the best way of doing this.

I used Excel's Forecast formula which uses linear regression.

I only have minor/very little knowledge in stats.

Comment: Time series modeling is a vast topic in statistics and social science. But, the logical hurdle that you have to clear is to establish that there is, indeed, some underlying systematic component to your data generating process: do you have information about these future months that might influence how this process unfolds? It is possible that the data are just coin flips or dice rolls, implying that attempting to predict them has little value.

Comment: Forecasts can be made using both quantitative and qualitative techniques. Perhaps you possess some specialist knowledge of the data that will allow you to make forecasts based on that information - qualitative judgement? As DJE has asked, do you have any information about the future months? Do you have to use quantitative techniques? Mike Flynn is correct in saying that not much can be said without knowing where the data comes from. Note that the models suggested by IrishStat and Zach are (quantitative) atheoretic models and you'd also want to be careful when using ARIMA models with <50 obs.

Comment: (cont.) You might "only have minor/very little knowledge in stats", but what do you know about the data itself? If you know a lot about it, you may be able to form forecasts based on expert judgement. So, what details do you know about the data and can it be shared?

Answer (score 8):

The [naive forecast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forecasting#Na.C3.AFve_approach) will probably outperform any kind of model you try to build here. The naive forecast is "tomorrow will be the same as today" or in this case, 177 for the rest of the year.

If you really must have a model, your best bet is probably something like [simple exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing).  It's possible to implement in excel, but [R is a much better tool](http://cran.us.r-project.org/):

```
x <- c(218, 185, 192, 87, 102, 103, 159, 172, 115, 146, 115, 117, 108, 88, 108, 109, 99, 177)
x <- ts(x, start=c(2012, 1), freq=12)
plot(x)

library(forecast)
ses(x, 6)
         Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Aug 2013       154.5251 106.76441 202.2858 81.48142 227.5688
Sep 2013       154.5251  96.04021 213.0100 65.08018 243.9700
Oct 2013       154.5251  86.99822 222.0520 51.25164 257.7986
Nov 2013       154.5251  79.03154 230.0187 39.06765 269.9826
Dec 2013       154.5251  71.82881 237.2214 28.05204 280.9982
Jan 2014       154.5251  65.20503 243.8452 17.92184 291.1284
```

As you can see, the forecast is a flat line:

```
plot(ses(x, 6))
```

[image]

/edit: as IrishStat points out, some other simple model, e.g. AR(1) would work too.  It's also important to know if any one time events affected your data and whether they will re-occur in the future.

Comment: There is no  magic number when it comes to estimating a model. There can be degrees of freedom issues when too many parameters are used leaving too few degrees of freedom. Back in the 1960's , someome one said you need at least 50 values to identify a model. This like all other rules of thumb can be "winked at" as being a guideline not a limit. The quote of 50 was based upon monthly data and 4 reps of the seasonal pattern might be reasonable to empirically identify the seasonal ARIMA structure. In this case there is too few to observations to empirically identify the seasonal structure.

Comment: ...cont The number of observations that is required to identify structure is based upon the ratio of signal to noise. The higher the ratio the fewer the number of observations. In this case (aside from seasonal structure) there is no evidence of a level shift or a time trend. A simple mean and an ar(1) is quite adequate while isolating 4 of the 19 values as inconsistent with that model. In a perfect world ( perhaps academia ) one can struggle with wanting to know the data and it's potential causes. In reality having tens of thousands of such series one wants to totally automate the process.

Comment: @IrishStat: Was this comment meant for the main post, perhaps in response to  Graeme Walsh's comment "you'd also want to be careful when using ARIMA models with <50 obs."?

Answer (score 2):

An appropriate model for this data is a simple AR(1).

[image]

The whole idea is to NOT assume a model NOR to ignore unusual values BUT to identify a minimally sufficient representation. The actual/fit/forecast graph is:

[image]

Even with 19 values it is sometimes possible to construct an equation which (reasonably) reflects the data and separates observations into signal and noise. This is a plot of the noise (residuals)

[image]

The residuals from an assumed exponential smoothing model are presented here for comparative analytics.

[image]

Notice the wide range for these residuals as compared to the empirically identified AR(1) model. The Excel Linear Regression model is also severly flawed as reflected by the following residual plot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't really say much about this data without knowing where the data comes from. To forecast you need a model. All models come with assumptions and if you can't tell whether these assumptions are held then you won't be able to have any confidence in the predictions. For example, in linear regression, you *assume* that you data represents a process of the form: $$ y_i = \beta x_i + e_i$$, the $e$ accounting for the data not exactly fitting the straight line. It so happens that in order to have any confidence in your predictions from this linear model, every $e$ must be independent from the other. Can you guarantee that? Also, the $e$'s must be normally distributed, does the problem make that assumption sensible? There are other assumptions as well, but I hope you now understand why you can't just give a statistician data and say "please predict what happens next".

Comment: "I hope you now understand why you can't just give a statistician data and say "please predict what happens next"." - That is sound advice, indeed.

Comment: Statistical characteristics that summarize the data can be used to suggest an appropriate model.Recall that all models are wrong but some are useful.If domain knowledge suggests logical predictors then they should be evaluated for their contribution. If "unusual data points" are identified then should be examined for "special cause" leading to increased understanding. The whole idea is to use what you have and if all that you have is the history then characterize that history in as simple a way as you can leading to a sufficient model that is parsimonious.

Comment: @IrishStat What you say is true, but one point is that we might know more than just the history! What are the details of this data? Is it an economic time-series? Is it a count of traffic accidents? Is is production data? Is it the number of miles someone has run at training? The OP may know the answer to these questions. If so, we may be able to use that information and other expert insight to form forecasts rather than just assume that all we have is the history of the time-series. At the moment, that's all we have, but the OP may have more information to share.